# Return em array js

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da velha em js, porém eu não consigo verificar se o índice preenchido é diferente de 1 ou 2. Alguma solução? Estou tentando dar return na array mas parece que não vai.

Código: https://jsfiddle.net/ew9kfhy3/

Erro no chrome:

> tictactoe.js:99
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at jogarIA (tictactoe.js:99)
>       at tictactoe.js:10

Comment: O erro está dizendo que não existe um elemento com aquele id, ao fazer `document.getElementById(id)` retorna null, ao fazer `innerHTML` em null da erro

Comment: mudei o negocio, mas o erro é o mesmo http://prntscr.com/jw40et o problema esta sendo q a IA ta conseguindo sobreescrever uma parte do vetor que ja tem algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observei 3 erros no seu código:

Nessas comparações `if(v[1] != 1 || v[1] != 2)` você poderia apenas fazer `if(!v[0]) {` para verificar se está vazio. Ou então deveria usar o operador `&&` em vez de `||`:

```
if(v[1] != 1 && v[1] != 2)
```

O operador `||` que significa `ou`, você está dizendo que pode ser direferente de 1 ou 2, logo se for vazio ou 1, irá validar, se for 2 também irá validar.

Outro erro similar é neste `if`:

```
if(v[randomIA] != 1 || v[randomIA] != 2) {
   v[randomIA] = 2;
```

Teria que usar ou `if(!v[randomIA]) {` ou `if(v[randomIA] != 1 && v[randomIA] != 2) {`. E o valor em `v[randomIA] = 2;` deveria, pela lógica, ser o valor randômico:

```
v[randomIA] = randomIA;
```

Outro problema é na geração de um número randômico:

```
randomIA = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 + 1));
```

Está gerando números de 0 a 9. Como os `id`s das `div`s vão de 0 a 8, retire o `+ 1`, porque está gerando o `9` e o JavaScript retorna o erro citado por não encontrar o elemento de `id="q9"`, que não existe.

Corrigindo esses problemas, o código parece funcionar perfeitamente. Veja (inclusive adicionei bordas para facilitar a visualização):

```js
var q;
var i;
var vez = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2) + 1);  // 1 para player / 2 para IA
var randomIA;
var posicaoOcupada;
var fimJogo = 0;
var flag = 0;
var v = new Array(9);   // 1 para player / 2 para IA
if(vez == 2)
    jogarIA();
function jogar(q) {
   posicaoOcupada = false;
    switch(q) {
        case 0:
            if(!v[0]) {
                v[0] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 1:
            if(!v[1]) {
                v[1] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 2:
            if(!v[2]) {
                v[2] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 3:
            if(!v[3]) {
                v[3] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 4:
            if(!v[4]) {
                v[4] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 5:
            if(!v[5]) {
                v[5] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 6:
            if(!v[6]) {
                v[6] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 7:
            if(!v[7]) {
                v[7] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
        case 8:
            if(!v[8]) {
                v[8] = 1;
            }
            else
                posicaoOcupada = true;
        break;
    }
    if(posicaoOcupada == true){
        document.getElementById("alerta").style.display = "";
    }else if(posicaoOcupada == false) {
        document.getElementById("q" + q).innerHTML = "X";
        jogarIA();
    }
    return v[q];
}
var randomLinha;
var randomColuna;
function jogarIA() {
    flag = 0;
    while(flag == 0) {
        randomIA = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));
        if(!v[randomIA]) {
            v[randomIA] = randomIA;
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
            flag = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("q" + randomIA).innerHTML = "O";
    return v[randomIA];
}
function mostrarIndex() {
 document.getElementById("index").style.display = "";
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("liIndex").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 window.location.href = "";
}
function mostrarTutorial() {
 document.getElementById("index").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("liIndex").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 window.location.href = "#tutorial";
}
function mostrarJogar() {
 document.getElementById("index").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("tutorial").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("jogar").style.display = "";
 document.getElementById("liIndex").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 document.getElementById("liTutorial").style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
 document.getElementById("liJogar").style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
}
```

```css
button {
 color: #777;
 background-color: #EEE;
 border: 1px #EEE solid;
}
button:hover {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #DDD;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
} 
ul#navbar {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #EEE;
 border: 1px #DDD solid;
}
li {
 float: left;
}
li a {
 color: #777;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
 background-color: #DDD;
 color: #000; 
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#main {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 550px;
 min-height: 500px;
 border: 1px #CCC solid;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
#logoDiv {
 background-image: url("../src/logo.png");
 height: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}
#headerDiv {
 border-bottom: 1px #CCC solid;
}
#bodyDiv {
 margin: 10px;
}
#q{
    width: 246px;
    height: 246px;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
 background: url("../src/grid.png");
}
.quadrado{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="main">
      <div id="logoDiv"></div>
      <div id="headerDiv">
         <ul id="navbar">
            <li id="liIndex" style="background-color: #CCC;"><a href="javascript:mostrarIndex();" id="indexNavbar">Página Inicial</a></li>
            <li id="liTutorial"><a href="javascript:mostrarTutorial();" id"tutorialNavbar">Tutorial</a></li>
            <li id="liJogar"><a href="javascript:mostrarJogar();" id="jogoNavbar">Jogar</a></li>
         </ul>

      </div>
      <div id="bodyDiv">
         <article id="index">
            <p>Bem vindo <span id="mostrarNome"></span> ao Jogo da Velha, descubra quais são as palavras antes que suas tentativas acabem.</p>
            <p>Caso não saiba jogar, clique na aba <b>Tutorial</b> para aprender. Caso já saiba, clique em <b>Jogar</b> para começar a diversão.</p>
         </article>
         <article id="tutorial" style="display: none;">
            <p>Nesse tópico, você verá como jogar o Jogo da Forca.</p/=>
         </article>
         <article id="jogar" style="display: none;" align: "center">
            <p id="placar" class="text-center"><b>Placar:</b><br><span id="placarPlayer">0</span> vs IA <span id="placarIA">0</span></p>
            <div id="q" class="text-center">
               <div id="q0" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(0);"></div>
               <div id="q1" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(1);"></div>
               <div id="q2" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(2);"></div>
               <div id="q3" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(3);"></div>
               <div id="q4" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(4);"></div>
               <div id="q5" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(5);"></div>
               <div id="q6" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(6);"></div>
               <div id="q7" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(7);"></div>
               <div id="q8" class="quadrado" onClick="jogar(8);"></div>
            </div>
            <p id="alerta" class="text-center" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Posição ocupada, tente outra!</p>
         </article>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: valeu mesmo mano, funcionou aqui :) ontem eu tava com sono e preocupado com provas, nem percebi esses errinhos bobos kk